# Physical reactions to sounds you know really well

Tags: physical-reaction

Hi folks

These last few days i've been editing sounds i've recorded during sailing trips.
I've sailed all of my life (including my life as a fetus haha) and not once i got sea sick,
but when i got to a file recorded during a particularly turbulent day, a stereo recording
of an interior perspective from the cabin, i got REALLY sea sick! as in my stomach wanting 
to get out....

Do you have similar experiences, of something that doesn't affect you at all while they're 
happening, but affect you deeply, when you're exposed to sounds or images?

Comment: Interesting, maybe you feel sick because you're not moving when your brain expects you to be?  You're so used to it that you do the opposite of other people?

Comment: Yeah i thought about that to...

Answer (score 3):

Not sound related, but it reminded me of this:
After a week of sailing around the Greece islands and sleeping on the boat, back on the mainland I slept badly for a few days because it felt like my bed was moving even though it wasn't.

And sound related: I did a binaural recording walking through the forest, with those microphones that you put in your ears. When listening back later that day while sitting outside, the sudden sound of a tree branch snapping behind me made me turn my head around to look for the source, but the sound was in the recording. During the recording it prompted no such reaction.

Comment: I get that "land legs," floaty-like-on-drugs feeling after having kayaked for a few hours on the ocean as well. One seems to notice it only when still, like on the couch or in bed. Back on-topic, I often find myself leaning left or right if a stereo image is unbalanced, and when imaging is great, I too find myself turning my head to perceived sound sources.

Answer (score 2):

Vacuum cleaner, hands down.

When I was a baby my mom discovered that whenever she vacuumed the house I would konk right out asleep. So obviously she used that as a sleeping pill for me all the time. If I was uppity or couldn't go down, she'd crank up the Hoover and I'd be out like a light.

To this day, if I hear my wife vacuuming in the next room it will usually end up with her waking me up a short time later, in a pool of my own adult baby drool. :P

Comment: @theodorejordan that's good one... I used to be the same way. I still get a bit drowsy when I hear one.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Room Ambience that I recorded in our Lobby that I tend to use on a lot of shows. In it is the sound of the studio phone ringing in the distance. Everytime I use that ambi and that phone is audible, I look over to see if the phone is ringing! :)

Answer (score 1):

I`ve made some recordings with a condom-sealed microphone dipping into the foam caused by fizzy tablets...everytime I listen to them my stomach starts to feel sick really fast.
When I was a kid we used to put several of those tablets in our mouth and try to hold it inside until the foam just swell out of our mouths. I guess this is why a start to feel sick =)

Answer (score 1):

I have a bit of light Tinnitus. Tinnitus has many variations, the most ordinary one being an audible beep, and another is that the ear recreates sounds that you hear or heard often. I have that variation. Whenever I hear a long kinda loud tone, like the tone of an organ or a sine wave, I always hear the wall clock of my parents house ticking... kinda spooky. And the weirdest part is that it's the clock sound I remember! I recall once I was trying to create a drone of some kind for a movie. And I couldn't focus on the sound I was creating cause I kept hearing the clock.

And that sound always brings me back to drinking chocolate milk and having sandwiches in my parent's house.

And I never put drones in my films :)